# How to add indicator-datetime to the panel?

Tags: 10.10, panel, indicator, gnome-panel

I'm using maverick desktop edition and I'd like to use indicator-datetime instead of the usual clock. I installed it using software center but even after restarting I don't find it in the "Add to panel" list. Maybe I'm trying to install it in the wrong way? Or should I add that indicator using terminal? If so, could you tell me how to do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently your indicator menus are loaded by either indicator-applet or indicator-applet-session, and none of those show the indicator-datetime menu.  You can replace those 2 applets, plus the old clock applet by 1 single applet indicator-applet-complete (and you have to install that one first).  The indicator-applet-complete applet will show indicator-datetime if it's installed.

So currently you have the following applets at the right side of the panel:

```
| notification area | indicator-applet | clock | indicator-applet-session |
```

And you have to change it to:

```
| notification area | indicator-applet-complete |
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a menu entry:

1. Go to ‘System > Preferences > Main Menu’
2. Choose ‘Accessories’ in the left-hand list
3. Click on the ‘New Item’ button
4. Choose a name and enter ‘indicator-workspaces’ for the command
5. Finalize by clicking the ‘Add’ button

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's not that what I mean. ;) I need to add an indicator to the top panel, not the menu item. In addition, I'm talking about indicator-datetime not indicator-workspaces :)