# On Ubuntu 20.04 - how to install WhatsApp Web?

Tags: whatsapp

I need to use WhatsApp on Ubuntu 20.04 and on Internet search found several links such as;

1. Install WhatsApp webapp on Ubuntu
   https://askubuntu.com/questions/6844...bapp-on-ubuntu
   etc.
2. WhatsApp webapp for Ubuntu
   https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/...untu#downloads

I have tried 2) above but failed.

Please advise?

Comment: What does failed mean? What error message what happens?

Comment: Can you edit the post and use the full links please? The links are currently broken due to the parts getting replaced by `...` in them.

Comment: Otherwise, unsure what's not working but WhatsApp web is just opening https://web.whatsapp.com in a browser and following the steps mentioned on that page.

Comment: Completely agree with @Dan .  There isn't a need to install software, app, or even a web browser extension.

Answer (score 2):

The app you require is Whatsdesk downloadable from the Ubuntu Software Center and has good reviews.

[image]

Comment: Hi David,

whatsapp-webapp_1.0_all.deb installation without problem

Applications -> WhatsAppl also started

But on my Android Phone (Samsung Galaxy S9 Plus), I couldn't find "Bar Code Scan" under WhatsApp -> Settings ?

Comment: @user108763 Tap the 3 vertical dots at the top right, then select "WhatsApp Web". It's the exact same instructions as of using the normal website. Again, no additional software required.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the snap store for this. Do:

`sudo apt install snapd`

Now restart your device.

`sudo snap install snap-store`

This should install the snap store on your device. It is GUI based and allows you to easily install whatsapp web. Or else, you can install using snap in terminal with

`sudo snap install whatsapp-for-linux`

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  It doesn't need any software.

Steps:-
On browser (in my case Firefox) run;
https://web.whatsapp.com/
The WhatsApp bar code popup on computer

On my Android phone
Start WhatsApp
Click the 3 dots
-> select WhatsApp Web
The bar code scanner popup

Point the scanner over WhatsApp bar code
After a while the WhatsApp screen of my Android phone popup on computer.

Then I can send and receive WhatsApp messages on my computer.

I came across some documents before about sending and receiving WhatsApp messages on computer without a mobile phone.  But I never tried it before.  Do any folk has any idea?  Thanks.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

"WhatsApp messages on computer without a mobile phone" , install anbox if you r on linux , you can also go for androidx86 install in virtualbox if you want the full experience and you can even install a full os like remix os on either virtualbox, or in dual boot(i recommend you anbox,cause you just need to use whatsapp, you can find many manuals on web on how to install it )

neverware was going in the right direction of implementing a os which can handle linux and android apps natively , but their google-partnership killed it(i maybe a bit wrong here)

but if you are on windows , i recommend MEmu android emulator, i have tried many others , but it is the best , out of them

**you can try signal or telegram , both are great , and have full cross-platform support

note: whatsapp's multi device is actually a feature in development(may take a lot time) and you can check about it on wabetainfo.com , also a whatsapp account can only be used on one single android device (means , if you install whatsapp on anbox or something else , you  wont be able to access the same account on your phone & vice-versa)

Comment: Hi Siddharth,

Thanks for your advice.

I have Anbox installed and running on Ubuntu 20.04, a VM client of Oracle VirtualBox.

Starting Anbox Session-Manager I couldn't find WhatsApp icon there.  Please advise how to add it?

Thanks

Comment: guide to help you create a shortcut,, https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-desktop-shortcut/

,,, you sure you installed whatsapp? go to https://m.apkpure.com/whatsapp-messenger/com.whatsapp/variant/2.21.8.17-APK
,, and drag drop the apk into anbox 
,,,, i dont know , if all the apk's shall work with anbox (go with x86 variant, cause thats the thing for emulators)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own WhatsApp web app on Ubuntu!

Here is a trick that is not known by most of the Ubuntu users:

1. Open terminal.
2. Type: `sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/whatsapp-webapp.desktop`.
3. Add the following:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=WhatsAppMW
   GenericName=WhatsAppMW
   Comment=WhatsAppMW desktop webapp
   Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app=https://web.whatsapp.com/
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   StartupNotify=true
   MimeType=text/plain;
   # If you want icon, type path of icon
   Icon=/home/mostafa/Music/whats.jpg
   Categories=Network;Application;
   Keywords=MostafaWael;webapp;
   X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=WhatsAppMW
   StartupWMClass=web.whatsapp.com
   ```
4. Hit save and now you can find your desktop app in the application menu.

---

N.B.:

- You can use any editor instead of `gedit` and you can use any names you want.
- If you are not using chrome, make sure to change `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`
  with your browser path.
- Firefox doesn't natively support installing websites as applications yet
- valid for anything, not only whatspp.